# Loading TTF file Font in BlackBerry OS 4.6

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I would like to know, is it possible to load font (.ttf file from resource) in Blackberry OS 4.6? I did it in BB OS 5.0 using FontManager class like to port application for 4.6 too.

Thanks and Regards
Anish

Answer (score 1):

For OS versions prior to 5.0 is not possible.

Comment: Thanks Mister Smith, Is there is any alternative? Such as install ttf font from a url, then use it in application..

Comment: Not using the Java API. Of course you could look for a library (or develop your own) for rendering fonts over a Graphics object.